# strip '\n' from lines of multiple simultaneously opened files

Tags: python

I need to open a small but variable number of files, each of which has the same number of lines. I then need to return a tuple of the lines in each. My code returns a tuple, but each element retains its '\n'; how to strip this before it gets packed into the tuple?

this is the code so far

```
files = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
fds = [ open(file) for file in files ] # gets all file open at same time
read_fds = izip( *fds )
for tpl in read_fds:
    print tpl    # will become a 'yield' stmt once the '\n' is sorted
for fd in fds:
    fd.close()
```

I have a test set of 3 files, each with 5 lines, each which indicates file number line number. The code prints this accurate record of these test files.

```
('f1ln1\n', 'f2ln1\n', 'f3ln1\tthis\tthat\n')
('f1ln2\n', 'f2ln2\n', 'f3ln2\tthis\tthat\n')
('f1ln3\n', 'f2ln3\n', 'f3ln3\tthis\tthat\n')
('f1ln4\n', 'f2ln4\n', 'f3ln4\tthis\tthat\n')
('f1ln5\n', 'f2ln5\n', 'f3ln5\tthis\tthat\n')
```

So far so good, but how to strip() that '\n' from each line before it gets packed into the tuple?

I know there's an answer out there! Looking fwd to suggestions. Thank you & have a great day.

Comment: the long way is to strip each line, one by one (while reading line by line)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use slicing of the string

```
for tpl in read_fds:
    list_stripped = []
    for s in tpl:
        list_stripped.append(s[:-1])
    print tuple(list_stripped)
```

Comment: You made the same mistake as I did, it's a tuple you're operating on, not a string. Also if there's no newline at the end of the file, your soultion will truncate the data.

Comment: Edited to operate on the string instead of the tuple. Thanks Stefan!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for tpl in read_fds:
    templist = []
    for item in tpl:
        templist.append(item.rstrip("\n"))
    print tuple(templist)
```

This will remove any newline character on the right side of the string

Comment: Edited because I treated the tuple as a string... Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to modify the assignment to `read_fds` so that it generates modified tuples from `izip`:

```
read_fds = (tuple(s.rstrip() for s in tup) for tup in izip(*fds))
```

However, I have not tested this.